# Populate command line buffer with last command in case of error

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to implement a way to put back the previous command in case of an error in Fish. However the following always results in an empty command line.

```
function __process_last_cmd -e fish_postexec
  set -lx error $status
  set -lx cmd (commandline)
  if test $error -ne 0
    commandline $cmd
  end
 # history delete -C --exact $cmd
end
```

(There is also a secondary operation where the command is de-duped from history, which I've left in the code in case it's relevant.)

Comment: Why do you export your local variables?

Comment: @glennjackman residual code from various attempts at making it work

Comment: No need to explicitly de-dup in that fashion as fish always stores only the most recent execution of a command; i.e., fish automatically de-dups the command history. Also, this sort of thing is rather silly IMO since all you have to do is press [up-arrow] or [ctrl-P] to retrieve the previous command.

Comment: i've had mixed results with fish's deduping, eg. https://imgur.com/a/sX4f1 ... maybe i don't understand how it actually works so i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fish_postexec` event is documented to provide the command line to the function as the first argument, so use

```
set -l cmd $argv[1]
```

https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function